# Change formula to Subtotal

Tags: excel, vba

I have this formula

```
=SUM((Usages!$BR$2:$BR$1065<BX2)+(Usages!$BS$2:$BS$1065>
  BX2)+INT(Usages!$AD$2:$AD$1065)-INT(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$1065)-1)
```

is there a way to convert it to Subtotal? so that my totals change as i filter data.

Here is a data sample, the formula works to count the frequency in which an hour bin has passed.

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feMkM.png)

Comment: Maybe the `AGGREGATE` function is what you are looking for. It allows you to ignore hidden rows.

Comment: I tried it but i have no idea how to make it work, =AGGREGATE(9,7,(($BR$2:$BR$1065<BX2)+($BS$2:$BS$1065>BX2)+INT($AD$2:$AD$1065)-INT($AB$2:$AB$1065)-1)) gives me #VALUE!

Comment: @bobby can you include a sample of your data so we can see what you are trying to do? The formula you've given in your question doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I have added a data sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(SUBTOTAL(103, OFFSET(BR1, ROW(1:1064), 0)), BR2:BR1065, 1E+99)<A3)+
               (SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET(BS1, ROW(1:1064), 0))>A3)+
            INT(SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET(AD1, ROW(1:1064), 0)))-
            INT(SUBTOTAL(109, OFFSET(AB1, ROW(1:1064), 0)))-
           1)
```

Before hiding rows(9:10):

[image]

After hiding rows(9:10):

[image]

Comment: It turns BR2:BR1065 into 1064 pieces that are processed individually instead of one big range (which subtotal cannot handle).

Comment: I see, does it work for you when you only take the last row or last few rows?

Comment: Sorry but I really didn't understand that last remark. It operates on rows 2:1065 in 4 different columns and disregards any rows that are hidden.

Comment: i tried filtering the rest (row2-8) and only selected 1.9(row 9) and 1.4(row 10), it gave me negative numbers based on your spreadsheet

Comment: Well that's likely because I only have 10 rows of data, not 1064 like your example formula. The negatives are probably coming from that *minus one* that you stuck on the tailend. Reshape the ranges to match you actual data and you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a better look at it and for your first criteria (`(Usages!$BR$2:$BR$1065<A3)+(Usages!$BS$2:$BS$1065>
  A3)`), you can use this workaround :
`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A32<>G1)*SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A2:A32)-1,0)))`

[image]

I am not sure what is the use for you second criteria (`+INT(Usages!$AD$2:$AD$1065)-INT(Usages!$AB$2:$AB$1065)-1`) as I dont think it returns any valuable result ? At least not in a bottom total cell formula use ?